# onmouseover flickering if new text is shorter than original

Tags: php, html, css

I got a simple nav bar with a username on it, and when the mouse is over the username, it changes to the ammount of points the user has.

```
<li>
    <a onmouseover="this.innerHTML='<?php echo $row['points'] . " POINTS" ?>';" 
       onmouseout="this.innerHTML='<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>';">
  /*Default*/     <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></a>

</li>

              <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
```

This works very good, but if the username is longer than the ammout of points, it starts flickering when hovering on edge of the text.

Here is my solution:

```
 <li onmouseover="document.getElementById('pts').style.display='inline-block';document.getElementById('name').style.visibility='hidden';"
     onmouseout="document.getElementById('pts').style.display='none';document.getElementById('name').style.visibility='visible';">

     <div style="position:relative;"><a id=pts style="display: none;position:absolute;";><?php echo $row['points'] . " POINTS" ?></a><a id=name><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></a></div></li>

<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
```

Now this solves my first problem, however, now IF the NAME is shorter than the amount of points, the points dont fit into the div and creates 2 lines of text.

I think that what i need to do is to have a condition like `if Name is shorter`, do the first code, and `if name is longer`, do the second code?

Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: yes, use the title attribute.  That is what I would do, the issue is the mouse hovers over it, it shrinks, then the mouse is no longer over it, then it grows and the mouse is back over it, then it shrinks, rinse repeat.  You could do mouse over for the parent element that is larger, then change it, that is the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: You also have this error `<a id=pts style="... ;";><?php echo`  No quotes for `id` and an extra `;`